# git hub ![rejected] - Não consigo saber os arquivos pro github

Tags: git, github

Estou tentando mandar meu código para o *GitHub*, mas não consigo. Seguir um tutorial, então estou na pasta correta e tal. Fiz um `git add all`, dei `commit` em tudo, o `git status` aparece no “print” para vocês darem uma olhada, mas aí ocorre o erro.

Algumas tentativas antes ele também pedira meu login e senha do *GitHub*, porém agora nem isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei como resolver

Comment: já fiz o direcionamento correto também, na pasta .git, o arquivo config está mandando pro link do meu diretório devidamente criado no GitHub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro exibido acontece, basicamente, na seguinte situação:

- São feitas alterações no repositório remoto e essas alterações não são aplicadas no repositório local

No seu caso, a mensagem de erro específica o seguinte:

*As atualizações foram rejeitadas porque a ponta do ramo atual está atrasada em comparação com o repositório remoto. Integre as mudanças remotas (Usando `git pull …`) antes de “enviar” novamente.*

Porém, caso você tenha criados os repositórios de forma independente, por exemplo: você cria o repositório no *GitHub* e também cria um repositório local com `git init`, o *git* pode interpretar que são dois projetos distintos e nesses casos você irá obter o erro abaixo:

> ```
> fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
> ```

Por padrão, o `git merge`¹ se recusa a mesclar histórias que não compartilham um antepassado comum. Isso é raro de acontecer, mas caso aconteça, você pode utilizar o parâmetro [--allow-unrelated-histories](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull---allow-unrelated-histories).

Este parâmetro pode ser utilizado para substituir esta segurança ao combinar histórias de dois projetos que iniciaram suas vidas de forma independente, por exemplo:

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Atenção! Você não deve usar `–allow-unrelated-histories` em todos os casos, a menos que saiba o que é um histórico não relacionado e tenha certeza de que precisa. A verificação foi introduzida apenas para evitar desastres quando as pessoas mesclam projetos não relacionados por engano. ²

> ¹ O comando `git pull` é — basicamente — a junção dos comandos `git fetch` + `git merge`.

<sup>Referência:</sup>
<sup>² https://stackoverflow.com/a/39783462/9101590</sup>
<sup>https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull</sup>

Answer (score 2):

O *git* já está te mostrando o problema e a solução:

> ```
> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
> ```

Ou seja, você está com o branch desatualizada porque alguém já subiu algo para a área “remote” e você não trouxe essas mudanças. Para resolver, basta atualizar a seu branch:

```
git pull
```

Quando você fizer isso, talvez seja necessário fazer algum “merge” de arquivos, nessa situação o *git* vai alertar dos conflitos. Nesse caso você só precisa resolvê-los, e depois “commitar” as mudanças normalmente.

Comment: Mandei um git pull, o que eu deveria fazer agora? tento dar o push novamente?

Comment: Ainda não consegui fazer funcionar.

Comment: @GiovaneMachado apos fazer o `git pull`, qual resultado? Apareceu alguma mensagem de erro? Caso tenha ocorrido tudo “ok”, você fez o `git push origin <branch>` novamente? Apareceu alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: There is no tracking information for the current branch
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

Comment: O git pull retorna isso, e depois eu tentei fazer novamente git push origin master e o erro inicial repete

Comment: @GiovaneMachado utilize `git pull origin master` e caso não dê certo, utilize `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master`. Dessa forma ele irá baixar as alterações do *branch master*

Comment: O primeiro retornou: 
From https://github.com/GiovaneMachado/my-first-blog
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

E o segundo retornou que o branch master nao existe

Comment: @GiovaneMachado Tente fazer `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` ou `git fetch origin`. Se você criou os repositórios (local e remoto) de forma independente, ao invés de clonar o repositório remoto, esse é o motivo do erro.

Comment: O primeiro funcionou! Logo fiz um git push e está tudo no meu Git Hub. Sem palavras cara, muito obrigado. Pode me explicar como resolveu? Se puder fazer como uma resposta melhor, mas de qualquer forma, muito obrigado!

Comment: Nem deu pra responder, mas seria complementar com o que o @ValdeirPsr falou mesmo. Isso é necessário porque você não clonou o repositório. Quando você cria um do zero é necessário vinculá-lo ao repositório remoto pois localmente é como se a branch não existisse. O que a opção allow-unrelated-histories faz é juntar as mudanças de dois repositórios existentes para permitir o push.